# Are stationary sets closed under small nested intersections?

Tags: set-theory

**Question:** Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable regular cardinal. Let $\alpha < \kappa$ be a smaller ordinal, and let $(A_i)_{i < \alpha}$ be a downward-nested family of subsets of $\kappa$: $\cdots \subseteq A_{i+1} \subseteq A_i \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_0 \subseteq \kappa$. Suppose that each $A_i$ is [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_set) in $\kappa$. Does it follow that the intersection $\cap_{i < \alpha} A_i$ is also stationary in $\kappa$?

**Notes:**

- It's equivalent to ask whether $\cap_{i < \alpha} A_i$ must be nonempty. For if $\cap_i A_i$ is nonstationary, then its intersection with some club $C$ is empty; replacing $A_i$ with $A_i \cap C$, we obtain a small nested family of stationary sets with empty intersection.
- If the $A_i$ are in fact club in $\kappa$, then the answer is *yes*, and we don't require the family to be nested. This is the statement that the club filter is complete.
- If the $A_i$ are assumed to be stationary but not nested, then the answer is *no* -- in fact, Solovay showed that the $A_i$ can be disjoint.
- From the analogy which says that stationary sets are like sets of positive measure, I'm tempted to guess the answer is *no*, since an $\omega$-sequence of subsets of $\mathbb R$ which are of positive measure can have empty intersection (e.g. $\cap_{i \in \mathbb N} [i,\infty) = \emptyset$).
- But if the analogy is more like "stationary sets are like comeager sets", then I think maybe I'm tempted to think the answer might be *yes*?

Comment: Ah, right, of course! Thanks, I'll accept your answer as soon as the software allows me to.

Comment: The Baire category analog of "stationary" is "non-meager", not "comeager". "Comeager" is the analog of "closed unbounded".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solovay's result also applies here: let $A_i$ be a sequence of disjoint stationary sets and let $B_j=\bigcup_{i>j}A_i$. The $B_j$s are nested and descending stationary sets whose intersection is empty.

(Of course, this parallels the $\bigcap[i,\infty)=\emptyset$ observation.)